# Increase spacing after brackets

Tags: math-mode, spacing, macros

I like Charter BT,
but the space between `)` and `y` is too narrow for me (Similarly `(` and `w` ).
I want to know how to write a macro to insert spaces between in math mode.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    uvw\qty(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i)yz
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

I tried `\renewcommand{\qty}[1]{\qty##1 \hspace{0.2em}}`,
but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small space can be inserted by `\,`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    uvw\,\qty(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i)\,yz
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

TeX automatically adds some space, if `\left` and `\right` are used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    uvw\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i\right)yz
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

If `\qty` should be used, then it can be wrapped in `\mathinner`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    uvw\mathinner{\qty(\sum_{i=1}^n a_ix^i)}yz
  \end{align}
\end{document}
```